# How to make a window always on top?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, qt5, window-managers, compiz

I have created a frameless Qt/QML window, and I really would like to know any programmatic means of setting its "Always On Top" system menu flag. Clicking <kbd>ALT+SPACE</kbd> I can bring up the system menu for the frameless window, and by clicking the "Always On Top" option the window does keep always on top, but I've not found a programmatic way of doing the same. The `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` doesn't work, and trying `wmctrl -r "window name" -b add,above` doesn't work either, even though `wmctrl` does work for other windows. `wmctrl` not working for my window of interest apparently has something to do with the `N/A` for the machine name column on `wmctrl -l`:

```
francisco@Ubuntu:~$ wmctrl -l
0x02600006  0 Ubuntu Área de trabalho
0x03c00002  0 Ubuntu XdndCollectionWindowImp
0x03c00005  0 Ubuntu unity-launcher
0x03c00008  0 Ubuntu unity-panel
0x03c0000b  0 Ubuntu unity-dash
0x03c0000c  0 Ubuntu Hud
0x046000b3  0 Ubuntu How to make a window aways on top? - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
0x0520000b  0    N/A Qt Creator
0x05002396  0 Ubuntu francisco@Ubuntu: ~
0x0540000b  0    N/A backlight
```

I've also gone through [this procedure](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=3749) but as for the user asking, it's not working for me either, same behavior. The `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE` is set, but focusing the window and then checking the flag again it's not there anymore, it's sticky only when clicking through system menu.

This is the QML: https://gist.github.com/oblitum/8050586

Related askubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/394998

### EDIT

#### Notice

In the related askubuntu question, it was found that there should be a bug on wmctrl for targeting certain windows through their names. Using `wmctrl -i -r <window id> -b add,above` also solves the issue.

Comment: The question is if Unity properly implements this behavior. Does Unity offer a way to the user to keep a window always on top?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld As I said, it's working by setting "Aways On Top" on system menu. I'd like to have the same programmatically.

Comment: I think Frank understood that, and he replied respectively. ;-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp I'm not getting, I'm a user, I'm using Ubuntu with Unity, and I can set the flag with the mouse, so?

Comment: So, he understood that you would like to get it programatically, do not worry. This was a first validation step. Anyways, what does it mean "Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint does not work"? Anything more than just nothing is changing? Console output, etc? Have you tried to track the internals of that down?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I have not pin down that yet.

Comment: Well, I've found this question and answer really useful, sad that it's downvoted...

Comment: winctrl can do this with 'wmctrl -i -r  WIN_ID  -b add,above'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the EWMH specification explicitly states that:

> _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE and _NET_WM_STATE_BELOW are mainly meant for user preferences and **should not be used by applications** e.g. for drawing attention to their dialogs (the Urgency hint should be used in that case, see [the section called “Urgency”](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#URGENCY)).

so window managers have no responsibility to respect applications which set this property directly (i.e by XChangeProperty) by themselves. this property can be changed only by sending a client message to the root window
which window managers listens on.

i don't know how to do it in high-level gui toolkits like Qt, but here is how to do it in plain X11.(see EWMH spec, or [_wnck_change_state](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libwnck/tree/libwnck/xutils.c) for a sample implementation).

```
//file: test.c
//to build it, run
//shell> gcc test.c -lX11

#include <X11/Xlib.h>   

#define _NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE        0    /* remove/unset property */
#define _NET_WM_STATE_ADD           1    /* add/set property */
#define _NET_WM_STATE_TOGGLE        2    /* toggle property  */


// change a window's _NET_WM_STATE property so that it can be kept on top.
// @display: x11 display singleton.
// @xid    : the window to set on top.
Status x11_window_set_on_top (Display* display, Window xid)
{
    XEvent event;
    event.xclient.type = ClientMessage;
    event.xclient.serial = 0;
    event.xclient.send_event = True;
    event.xclient.display = display;
    event.xclient.window  = xid;
    event.xclient.message_type = XInternAtom (display, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
    event.xclient.format = 32;

    event.xclient.data.l[0] = _NET_WM_STATE_ADD;
    event.xclient.data.l[1] = XInternAtom (display, "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE", False);
    event.xclient.data.l[2] = 0; //unused.
    event.xclient.data.l[3] = 0;
    event.xclient.data.l[4] = 0;

    return XSendEvent (display, DefaultRootWindow(display), False,
                       SubstructureRedirectMask|SubstructureNotifyMask, &event);
}

// a sample main function for testing.
// shell> ./a.out window_xid
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    Window xid = strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0); 
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay (NULL);

    x11_window_set_on_top (display, xid);

    XFlush (display); //for simplicity, no event loops here.

    XCloseDisplay (display);
}
```

also note that in some x11 environment(e.g. compiz), system menus are provided by a separate decorator program instead of the compositing window manager.

Answer (score 0):

In Go, this is how you do it:

```
import (
    "github.com/BurntSushi/xgb"
    "github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/xproto"
)

func (window *Window) AlwaysOnTop() {
    xid := xproto.Window(window.WinId())
    X, err := xgb.NewConn()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer X.Close()

    state, err := xproto.InternAtom(X, false, uint16(len("_NET_WM_STATE")),
        "_NET_WM_STATE").Reply()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    stateAbove, err := xproto.InternAtom(X, false,
        uint16(len("_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE")), "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE").Reply()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    evt := xproto.ClientMessageEvent{
        Window: xid,
        Format: 32,
        Type:   state.Atom,
        Data: xproto.ClientMessageDataUnionData32New([]uint32{
            _NET_WM_STATE_ADD,
            uint32(stateAbove.Atom),
            0,
            0,
            0,
        }),
    }

    err = xproto.SendEventChecked(X, false, xproto.Setup(X).DefaultScreen(X).Root,
        xproto.EventMaskSubstructureRedirect|xproto.EventMaskSubstructureNotify,
        string(evt.Bytes())).Check()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

where `window.WinId()` is the native X11 handle of a window.

Answer (score -1):

I hope i understood the problem correctly as you were trying to launch a QML view into "Always On Top" mode through a menu option.

I tried the following code, on windows, into my main and it worked for me to show the window always on top, so i believe the view object can be altered from menu option as well.

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QDeclarativeView viewer;
**viewer.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);**
viewer.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("TestView.qml"));
viewer.showNormal();
return app.exec();
```

Thanks,
Zeeshan

Comment: sorry, but as I said, this `WindowStaysOnTopHint` doesn't work, the QML window launches with this flag alrealdy set.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.
when i comment setting the window style with WindowStaysOnTopHint, i observe my window is not always on top
and hence as soon as i apply setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint); window always stay on top.
so i believe QML does not default set this flag while launching it. 
i would suggest to run the sample and observe the behaviour

Comment: The way I had tried to set it for a QQuickWindow, which is the root object I get, is `mywindow->setFlags(mywindow->flags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)`. This didn't work

Comment: I just read the documentation on Qt:WindowsStaysOnTopHint which says in some case you may also need to pass Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint flag to make it work correctly.
for further detail please go through http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#WindowType-enum link where you will find a Note stating
"Note that on some window managers on X11 you also have to pass Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint for this flag to work correctly." Hope this would solve the issue